# OnPremise: Sharepoint Hosted App gives 401 unauthorized error while accessing after deploying it through Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am getting 401 Unauthorized error after deploying default Sharepoint Hosted App.
I have done no changes app, it is just a default app with Full control permission in AppMenifest file..

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a dev machine, maybe you're connecting to your SharePoint with a SharePoint service account such as SPFarm or the account running the app pool, resulting in being logged on as "System account".
Apps cannot be deployed with System Account... You must be logged as someone else.

Comment: I am using different credential other than these accounts. App is deployed and installed successfully, but getting 401 Unauthorized only when i am going to open or access it.

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use on your Web application? Kerberos or NTLM?

Comment: I am using NTLM for authentication.